# BigQuery SQL Error: Name rank not found inside latest at [9:15]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

I'm using a query pasted from documentation to deduplicate a BigQuery dataset. When I use the query, I get an error:

> Name rank not found inside latest at [9:15]

And I just can't understand why. Note: I'm new to SQL. The query in question is below:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT *,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY gregoriandate 
                     ORDER BY _sdc_report_datetime DESC)
        FROM hf_bing.campaign_performance_report
        ORDER BY gregoriandate ASC
       ) AS latest
 where latest.rank = 1
```

Comment: can you point us to the doc page with this query? we could fix it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this already solves for you:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY gregoriandate ORDER BY _sdc_report_datetime DESC) AS rank_
  FROM hf_bing.campaign_performance_report
 )
 WHERE rank_ = 1
```

When you used `WHERE latest.rank = 1`, there's actually no field named `rank` in `latest` which results in the error you got. I basically used an alias for the field so now BigQuery knows precisely which field is being referenced.